# Proof that every subspace is a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I was unable to find a simple proof that a subspace is a vector space. I know that a subspace $S$ is a subset of a vector space, such that:

$$\vec 0 \in S\\\vec a + \vec b \in S\\\alpha\vec a \in S$$

For the first case, I know that $\alpha = -1 \implies -\vec a \in S$

But how can we prove that $\vec a + \vec b = \vec b + \vec a$? We know that $S$ is a subset of a vector space, so the laws of the space are valid (it should be valid, then, the associativity law for $a$ and $b$). But what I don't understand, is why we can simply check for $\vec 0 \in S,\vec a + \vec b \in S,\alpha\vec a \in S$ and then conclude this subspace is also a vector space. We don't know yet, so we can't assume the laws of vector space are valid.

Comment: "We don't know yet, so we can't assume the laws of vector space are valid." You can assume it for the larger vector space, that is given. From the larger one, you can infer things for the smaller one.

Comment: @GitGud but my teacher said that we can just verify the $3$ conditios, and then say that the set is a vector space. So there should be a way to prove that $\vec 0 \in S, \vec a + \vec b \in S, \alpha \vec a \in S \implies \vec a + \vec b = \vec b + \vec a$.

Comment: And there is. Read the answers. You know that $$\forall \vec{a},\vec b\in V(\vec a+\vec b=\vec b+\vec a)\implies \forall \vec  a,\vec b\in S(\vec a+\vec b=\vec b+\vec a),$$ because $S\subseteq V$. You don't even need the conditions to conclude this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already know $\vec a+\vec b=\vec b+\vec a$ when you calculate the two sides in the larger vector space. But that is exactly what you do when you calculate sums in the subspace too -- the sums are the same no matter whether you think of the elements as living in the subspace or in the original space.

Because equality holds in the original space, it must hold in the subspace too.

Comment: But my teacher said that we can simply check for the $3$ conditions for a subspace, and then conclude it is a vector space. I don't see why these closure and existence of the 'null' elemento, implies associativity and the other things necessary for a vector space. In other words, I know that if we define a subspace as a subset of a vector space, then it is also a vector space. But I can't see why any set that satisfies these $3$ conditions is considered a vector space.

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs: It is not true that "any set that satisfies the 3 conditions is a vector space". What _is_ true is that "any set that _is a subset of a vector space_ and satisfies the 3 conditions is itself a vector space".

Comment: So there's no such thing as verifying these $3$ conditions, because it must say in the exercise that the set is a subset of a vector space...

Answer (score 1):

I'd show that $\vec{a} \in S$ and $\vec{b} \in S$.

You can do this by letting $\alpha = 0$ and observing that $0\vec{a} = \vec{0} \in S$, and hence $\vec{0} + \vec{a} = \vec{a} \in S.$  Similarly, $\vec{b} \in S$.  (More formally, you're showing the additive identity relationship for the subspace, which follow from the same relationship in the larger space.)

Now that the two individual vectors $\vec{a}, \vec{b} \in S$, and since in the larger vector space $\vec{a} + \vec{b} = \vec{b} + \vec{a}$, the same is true in $S$.

Comment: But why we can simply say that every set that satisfies the $3$ conditions is a vector space? I mean, we can't assume it is a vector space, and then prove these conditions. So, there must be a way that the 3 conditions implies laws like associativity, but I can't see how.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't say this explicitly:  There are more conditions than that.  I assumed that you had a list of the properties of a vector space.  I drew from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition).  You'll need to show these, or some equivalent set of axioms, but showing that $\vec{a}, \vec{b} \in S$ will help, I think.